# ReactJs: Rendering Similar React Components from a list without using same states for each of the element

Tags: reactjs

I have a `CustomReactComponent` class which holds a list of similar React Components, I then render a single element `Component` from the list based on some condition.
This `Component` has `<input/>` tag.
When I try to render it all the `<input/>` tags have the same value when User changes only one of them.

How can I prevent this from happening? and have the inputs store differnt values for each instance

**Minimal Reproducible Code:**

```
import {Component} from "react";

export default class CustomReactComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {selected: 0};
        this.list = [<div><input/></div>, <div><input/></div>, <div><input/></div>, <div><input/></div>];
    }

    onSelect = (e) => {
        this.setState({selected: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        let Component = this.list[this.state.selected];
        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    State:{this.state.selected}: 
                    {Component}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
As @asynts pointed out we could use `key` for each component, but `keys`'s  check for siblings during rendering, and since here i am rendering only a single component, `key` would be of no use, it re-initializes the component every time the state `selected` changes. But this is a start, it atleast dosent treat all the components in `this.list` as the same thing

**Edit 2:**
After some tinkering and experimentation I found a work around for this, we can have a Wrap Component which is given a unique id `uid` as a `prop` this can then be used during rendering if state `selected` points to `uid` of a Wrap we style it to `display: initial` else to `display: none`, this is where `key`'s comes handy we can always render all the siblings and give it a `key` same as `uid`

**Code:**

```
import {Component} from "react";

function Wrap({uid}) {
    return <div>uid = {uid} : <input/></div>
}

export default class CustomReactComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {selected: 0};
        this.list = [
            <Wrap uid={0}/>,
            <Wrap uid={1}/>,
            <Wrap uid={2}/>,
            <Wrap uid={3}/>
        ];
    }

    onSelect = (e) => {
        this.setState({selected: parseInt(e.target.value)});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                State:
                <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    {this.list.map((component) =>
                        <div key={component.props.uid}
                             style={{display: component.props.uid !== this.state.selected ? 'none' : 'initial'}}>
                            {component}
                        </div>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How many input  do you want ?

Comment: Its actually dynamic, `this.list` will contain react elements which can have n-inputs labels etc etc but each element will be similar, ie will have the same component structure.
here its just for minimal reproduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `key` for each component, but `key`'s check for siblings during rendering, and here only a single component is being rendered, thus making `key` not so useful, it re-initializes the component every time the state `selected` changes.
But we can have a Wrap Component as a work around, Wrap is given a unique id `uid` as a `prop` this can then be used during rendering if state `selected` points to `uid` of a Wrap we style it to `display: initial` else to `display: none`, this is where `key`'s comes handy we can always render all the siblings and give it a `key` same as `uid`

**Code:**

```
import {Component} from "react";

function Wrap({uid}) {
    return <div>uid = {uid} : <input/></div>
}

export default class CustomReactComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {selected: 0};
        this.list = [
            <Wrap uid={0}/>,
            <Wrap uid={1}/>,
            <Wrap uid={2}/>,
            <Wrap uid={3}/>
        ];
    }

    onSelect = (e) => {
        this.setState({selected: parseInt(e.target.value)});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                State:
                <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    {this.list.map((component) =>
                        <div key={component.props.uid}
                             style={{display: component.props.uid !== this.state.selected ? 'none' : 'initial'}}>
                            {component}
                        </div>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a much more interesting problem than I originally thought.
It seems that React simply can't tell that you are rendering a different element.

Ultimately, the JSX syntax [is just syntactic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects) for `React.createElement` which returns an object:

```
// jsx:
<input />

// js:
React.createElement("input");

// result object:
{
    type: "input",

    // This is the default.
    key: null,

    // There is some other stuff in here too.
}
```

In other words, all the entries in your array are identical as far as React is concerned.

---

You can resolve this problem by specifying a `key` attribute in each array entry:

```
this.list = [
    <div key="1"><input/></div>,
    <div key="2"><input/></div>,
    <div key="3"><input/></div>,
    <div key="4"><input/></div>,
];
```

---

[There is some documentation about this but it's a bit vague.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

[Here is an in-depth explanation about why keys are necessary if you’re interested in learning more.](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

TL;DR: React will create a tree of these objects I mentioned and then computes the difference to the previous tree and updates the DOM. In your case, it is not able to find a difference and therefore needs the `key` attribute to help.

Comment: Yes you're right, I had considered using `key`, but there is a catch, since key checks for siblings, here i am not rendering any sibling (but just a single component), thus when i type in the input -> change the state `selected` come back an entirely new component instance is rendered, it does not remember the prev input state

Comment: You should not keep state in the DOM elements. Use `useState` instead, example: https://jsfiddle.net/shdn2ufg/1/

Comment: But if the component is more complex that might not be an option, @AmithM provided a workaround for that in his answer.